# Are there any plans to raise from the dead r/StackOverflow and r/StackExchange subreddits in the near future?

Tags: discussion, reddit

This past year the company has committed to "Community growth" as one of the priority points on the to-do list. I was wondering if that includes (re)taking ownership of the subreddits named after [the community](https://reddit.com/r/stackexchange/new/) and [its biggest site](https://reddit.com/r/stackoverflow/new/). For now there is almost no activity on either subreddit.

They could be used to post links to SO.Blog post articles and featured posts on all meta sites, so that users with Reddit accounts could have lengthy threaded conversations in the comments over there. As I don't see threaded comments coming to the SE/SO site engine anytime soon, this might be a great alternative to… well, there is nothing of that sort available to users here at the moment in terms of free long form discussions on distinct topics which won't intermix or disappear upwards into chat transcript.

Comment: has there ever really been ownership of either? What would be the process of taking over ownership, and who would actually run it?

Comment: What is the story of those? E.g. when and why were they created? Is it formal ownership (or de facto)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those were set up a long time ago as a place for people to talk about Stack Overflow and the SE network outside of meta. At the time, we were a completely new concept, and folks naturally wanted to talk *about* the site on a very theoretical, abstract and subjective level that didn't fit UserVoice or even Meta. It made sense for us to have the space for that, with the ability to use mod powers to keep things from going off the rails if needed.

I'm not going to try to grow a new community there - I'll continue to keep an eye on it and if interest returns, well, we can go from there. But, it's not something I can spend a whole lot of time on.

We don't have threaded comments but ... I'm not sure if re-building things just for utility purposes is a great use of time either.

To be clear, I'd love to see a community return there; I just don't see anything in our current or future circumstances that might cause that to happen. But, I'll continue to keep an eye on it.

Answer (score 11):

What for??

From quick look in the existing posts, it's either people who hate Stack Exchange, or spam.

I see no point to revive bad things.

If anything, SO can create new subreddits from scratch, and manage them properly.

Comment: In other words, [no!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dGpW0.gif).

Answer (score 11):

I don't see a clear upside here. As Shadow [points out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/354844/622284), the current posts on both r/StackOverflow and r/StackExchange are either fairly low quality, from trolls who hate Stack Exchange, or just off topic.

While r/StackExchange doesn't have any recognizable moderators in its [list of moderators](https://www.reddit.com/r/stackexchange/about/moderators), about a month ago, Tim Post was added to r/StackOverflow's [list of moderators](https://www.reddit.com/r/stackoverflow/about/moderators), but I don't expect much to come of it.

Tim Post goes into further detail about his plans for the subreddit in [this comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/stackoverflow/comments/g11v8f/can_we_get_some_mods_in_here/g2xr1s1/?context=3). Quoting some of his comment...

> Let me get familiarized and, if it looks like we've got a community here that wants to talk about SO, I'm happy to help.

I don't see the potential for a community to thrive over on r/StackOverflow at the present time. Should traffic increase and Tim Post want to put some time into subreddit design and subreddit rules, I suppose it *could* work out... But I don't think the effort is worth the potential benefit at the moment.

Answer (score 10):

Those aren't *our* communities, so there's nothing for *us* to resurrect.

If whomever created them wanted to resurrect them as a place for them to rant about the network, let 'em; it has nothing to do with us.  I wouldn't see it any differently than the rants that take place on other social media sites.